# Hugging Face H5 load model error : No model found in config file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to load model from Hugging Face and I downloaded h5 model from here: https://huggingface.co/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english/tree/main

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request  # import objects from the Flask model
from keras.models import load_model
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification,TextClassificationPipeline

model = load_model('./tf_model.h5') # trying to load model here
```

And the error shows up:

```
File "C:\D\Learning\Flask\flask-pp-rest\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    model = load_model('./tf_model.h5') File "C:\Users\ndrez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py",
line 200, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, File
"C:\Users\ndrez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py",
line 176, in load_model_from_hdf5
    raise ValueError('No model found in config file.') ValueError: **No model found in config file.**
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? If you know please help me out. I will monitor this question and try to implement your solution's answer.

Comment: Where did you get  this h5 file or how did you make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the tensorflow version of `distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english` with the [TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.5.1/model_doc/auto.html#transformers.TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification) class:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")
```

Answer (score 0):

To load the model you specified, this is the code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")
```

Comment: i have tried this and it requires pytorch, I just want to use tensorflow